# Simulation result differing between parallel and serial implementations (And Compiler settings)

Tags: c++, statistics, openmp

I'm conducting some Monte Carlo simulations for uni and I've noticed that I get slightly different results depending on whether I run my code serially or in parallel. I generate data points (x[i]) from the Weibull distribution, compute the (theoretical) CDF at x[i] and then compare that to the empirical CDF (1/n) through the KS test. I do this 10,000 times and then print the 95% value to a csv file. This whole procedure is repeated 100 times, so the resulting csv is one column with 100 rows. I take the mean of these (manually in Libre Math) and get the following results for the different scenarios

Serially:
Mean = 1.340 +/- 0.001 which is the correct value (I have a benchmark to compare against)

Parallel:
Mean = 1.345 +/- 0.002

I'm Compiling with g++ 5.4.0 and the following flags

```
    -fopenmp -fno-inline -std=c++17 -g -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -Wall
```

The error margins are just what I've observed and aren't statistically rigorous. The difference is enough to effect my conclusion. This is a drastically simplified version of the real code and all of my initial thoughts (e.g. objects being shared) didn't fix the problem.

Additionally I've noticed that if I include the following optimisation flag I get the same ( and correct ) for both serial and parallel cases.

```
 -Ofast
```

My question is

1) Why do I get different results?

2) What am I doing to upset the compiler in one case but not the other?

For interests sake, I'm running this on a dual core machine, that's been hyper-threaded to have 4 logical cores.
Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h> 
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>


// INITIAL
const float scale = 400.0; const float shape = 0.577; 
const int n=100;    
const int numOfCV=100;const int numOfSims=10000;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 e2(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_dist(0, 1);

int main(){

   // DETERMINE NUMBER OF CORES
    const unsigned Cores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout<<"Cores="<<Cores<<std::endl;
    omp_set_num_threads(Cores);
    //OPEN OUTPUT FILE
    std::ofstream csvfile; csvfile.open("KS_D95.csv");

    #pragma omp parallel for // I comment this line out to run serially
    for(int CV_inc = 0; CV_inc < numOfCV; ++CV_inc){

      double x[n];
      double CDF_emp[n];
      double CDF_theory[n];
      for(int i=0; i<n ;++i){
          CDF_emp[i]=(1.0+i)/n;
      }
        double DnP[numOfSims];
        double D95;
        double dt;
        double dt0;

        int simNum = -1;
        while(simNum < numOfSims-1 ){simNum++;
            // GENERATE DATA POINTS
            for(int i=0; i<n ;++i){
                x[i] = scale*pow(-log(uniform_dist(e2)),1/shape);
            }
            // CALCULATE CDF        
            for(int i=0; i<n ;++i){
                CDF_theory[i]=1-exp(-pow(x[i]/scale,shape));
                if ( std::isinf(CDF_theory[i])) {
                    printf("CDF_theory[i]=%f \n",CDF_theory[i]);
                }
            }
            std::sort(CDF_theory,CDF_theory+n);

            // KS TEST 
            dt=0.0;dt0=0.0;
            for(int i=1; i<n ;++i){
            if (dt<std::abs(CDF_theory[i]-CDF_emp[i])){
            dt=std::abs(CDF_theory[i]-CDF_emp[i]);
                }
            if (dt0<std::abs(CDF_theory[i]-CDF_emp[i-1])){
                dt0=std::abs(CDF_theory[i]-CDF_emp[i-1]);
            }
        }
            DnP[simNum]= sqrt(n)*std::max(dt,dt0);
        }
        // PRINT RESULT
        std::sort(DnP,DnP+numOfSims);
        D95=DnP[(int)(numOfSims*0.95)-1];
        std::cout<<"line complete, KS_D95="<< D95 <<std::endl;
        csvfile<<D95<<std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Random numbers being generated in one thread vs being generated in 2 or more threads.  The 1 thread version is deterministic the 2 or more thread version is not due to thread scheduling.

Comment: Thanks Richard, how can I amend this? how does thread scheduling make the multi-threaded version non-deterministic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each thread build its own version of the random generator. 
A super naive way to do it is to move the following three lines in the `parallel loop`

```
    #pragma omp parallel for // I comment this line out to run serially
    for(int CV_inc = 0; CV_inc < numOfCV; ++CV_inc){
       std::random_device rd;
       std::mt19937_64 e2(rd());
       std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_dist(0, 1);
```

This way each thread has an indipendent random number generator.

Using this I get the following results (parallel on 8 cores):

```
 ------------------------------
|  RUN |  SERIAL    | PARALLEL |
|   1  | 1.3407766  | 1.3405413|    
|   2  | 1.3398708  | 1.3400575|
|   3  | 1.3404915  | 1.3414703|
|   4  | 1.3406889  | 1.3402073|
--------------------------------
```

A better way to initialize those stuff is to use a `parallel` region and a `for` separately as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 e2(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_dist(0, 1);
#pragma omp for  // I comment this line out to run serially
    for (int CV_inc = 0; CV_inc < numOfCV; ++CV_inc) {
```

---

What's happening here I guess is that the random generator is initialized with the same seed for each thread, hence each independent call number `i` from each thread generates the very same number. This means you're using the same sequence of numbers on all threads. You need a different seed for each thread.

Comment: Thanks Davide, this works a treat :) as a matter of interest, do you know why this wasn't a problem when I used the optimisation flag?

Comment: @JakeCG What I think happens is that the since *uniform_distribution* objects is relatively simple and small the compiler inlines them. BTW, On my machine with g++7, I get wrong results even using aggressive optimizations.